# one-hot encoding from floating point index? (No gradients provided for any variable with Generalized Dice Loss)

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, loss-function, one-hot-encoding

I'm building an Unet-based neural network architecture for an I2I translation task using a paired dataset [input image, ground_truth].

The model takes in input an RGB image of shape 64x64x3 and produces in output an image of 64x64x3. I'd like to compare the ground truth with the generated image by using a particular custom loss function.
In a nutshell, the ground truth and the generated image feed a trained model that outputs 2 masks of 64x64x3 where each pixel belongs to {0,1,2,3}. I'd like to compare them making a loss value.

I thought that Generalized Dice Loss might be good, and I found an implementation here: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/9395.

I tried to use it, but I got:

```
ValueError: in user code:

    File "/var/folders/6z/93vfmb1930j2ys97s5xf8tp00000gn/T/ipykernel_61471/2960572911.py", line 11, in train_step  *
        generator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(generator_gradients,
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/optimizers/optimizer.py", line 1222, in apply_gradients  **
        grads_and_vars = self.aggregate_gradients(grads_and_vars)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/optimizers/optimizer.py", line 1184, in aggregate_gradients
        return optimizer_utils.all_reduce_sum_gradients(grads_and_vars)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/optimizers/utils.py", line 33, in all_reduce_sum_gradients
        filtered_grads_and_vars = filter_empty_gradients(grads_and_vars)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/optimizers/utils.py", line 77, in filter_empty_gradients
        raise ValueError(

    ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable:
```

The loss function I used is :

```
def dice_coef_4cat(y_true, y_pred, smooth=1e-7):
    y_true_f = K.flatten(K.one_hot(K.cast(y_true, 'int32'), num_classes=4)[...,1:])
    y_pred_f = K.flatten(K.one_hot(K.cast(y_pred, 'int32'), num_classes=4)[...,1:])
    intersect = K.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f, axis=-1)
    denom = K.sum(y_true_f + y_pred_f, axis=-1)
    
    return K.mean((2. * intersect / (denom + smooth)))

def dice_coef_4cat_loss(y_true, y_pred): 
    return 1 - dice_coef_4cat(y_true, y_pred)

def generator_loss(target, gen_output):
    target_mask = trained_model(target)
    generated_mask = trained_model(gen_output)

    return dice_coef_4cat_loss(target_mask,generated_mask)
```

while the train_step is :

```
@tf.function
def train_step(input_image, target, step):
    with tf.GradientTape() as gen_tape :
        gen_output = generator(input_image, training=True)

        gen_loss = dice_coef_4cat_loss(target, gen_output)

    generator_gradients = gen_tape.gradient(gen_loss,
                                          generator.trainable_variables)
    
    generator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(generator_gradients,
                                          generator.trainable_variables))
```

With other kinds of loss functions, the architecture perfectly works, so the problem seems to be related to my custom, loss function.

Comment: Casting to int is not differentiable, so this loss has no usable gradients.

Comment: is there any way to convert it into a differentiable function?

Comment: you'll want to find a "one-hot" function that can take a floating point "index". I'd suggest it be a gaussian. centered at that "index".